# Gitlab CI Not able to use variable for branch reference in include project

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to import the CI pipeline from a different project. If i put the branch name in ref it works fine but when I try to use an env variable instead of hardcoded value, i get error.

gitlab-ci.yml contents

```
##inherit the shared pipeline
include:
  - project: automated-pipeline
    ref: $PIPELINE_BRANCH
    file: .gitlab-ci.yml
```

Status: syntax is incorrect

Project `automated-pipeline` reference `$PIPELINE_BRANCH` does not exist!

Answer (score 3):

Did stumble across this question because I have the same question.

Sadly this is not available yet. There is an open issue at Gitlab to support this feature:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/219065

Perhaps it's a good thing to keep track of it.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for this feature today and this worked for me.

**Solution by Adam Hartwell,**
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/219065#note_1388859457

Quick workaround with YAML anchors in case it's helpful for the meantime:

**variables:**
CI_REF: &CI_REF 1.0.0

**include:**

- project: "some/project"

  ref: *CI_REF

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Jesse I updated the answer and hope it works.